# How to create Symbolic link for linux web server

Tags: linux, symlink

How to create the symbolic link for the path on web server(linux).

Suppose I want to create link for request url

```
http://localhost:8059/layerslider/skins/fullwidth/skin.css
```

And the file is present on server at location

```
/home/users/assets/plugins/layerslider/skins/fullwidth/skin.css
```

Do anyone know about it????

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this is not good practice. But in some case we need to use it.

But you need to first allow the symbolic links for the domain.

You can do it with configuation file of apache.

Add this::  **Options FollowSymLinks**

Then you can create and apache2 allow to symbolic links.

```
ln -s original_folder_soruce symbolic_link_path_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating symbolic link does not recommended.

But you have option to on this facility.

In apache hosting confuguration file  add this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

And provide appropriate permission according to file needs.

And be specific answer to your question is:

create symbolic as

```
ls -s /home/users/assets/plugins/layerslider/ /web-rootFolder/layerslider
```

Comment: Isn't it ln -s ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the location of localhost on server side.

```
 sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

DocumentRoot /home/users/assets/plugins
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/users/assets/plugins
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

After save file (ctrl+o ctrl+x), restart apace.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

To change the port:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```